# Database First : Get the primary key value and the parent property value of an arbitrary entity

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity framework 6 , Database First. and VB.net.

I have a situation where :

- I have an object ( that is an entity object , but the class is known only on runtime ).
- I need to get ( and modify ) the value of Primary key and the value of Parent field ( if it's related ).

Is possible to get these?

Thank you !

**Update :**
Actually I have 2 functions that is supposed to return the names of Primary Key property and to a Foreign key property :

```
Public Function Get_pk(ctx As MyEntities, entity As Object) As String
    Dim objectContext = DirectCast(ctx, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
    Dim t As Type = entity.GetType.BaseType
    Dim m As MethodInfo = objectContext.GetType().GetMethod("CreateObjectSet", New Type() {})
    Dim generic As MethodInfo = m.MakeGenericMethod(t)
    Dim st As Object = generic.Invoke(objectContext, Nothing)
    Dim entitySetPI As PropertyInfo = st.GetType().GetProperty("EntitySet")
    Dim entitySet As Metadata.Edm.EntitySet = DirectCast(entitySetPI.GetValue(st, Nothing), Metadata.Edm.EntitySet)
    Dim keyNames As IEnumerable(Of String) = entitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(Function(k) k.Name)
    Return keyNames(0)
End Function
```

This is for Primary Key property , and is working , **but is slow** ( I'm thinking if Entity framework has a built in method to get this directly ??? )

```
Public Function Get_FK(ctx As MyEntities, entity As Object, parenttable As String) As String
        Dim fk = entity.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(Of Metadata.Edm.AssociationType)(Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.CSpace).Where(Function(a) a.IsForeignKey)
        Dim fkname = fk.Where(Function(x) x.ReferentialConstraints(0).ToRole.Name = parenttable) 
        Dim refcol = fkname.Select(Function(x) x.ReferentialConstraints(0).FromProperties(0).Name).First()
        return refcol
    End Function
```

This is for the foreign key (related with a parenttable that is passed as parameter ). **This is not working**. I get an error in the first line because entity is a proxy object and MetaDataWorkspace is not a member of proxy types. and I don't know if this function works at all.

What can I do ?

Thank you !

Comment: Is the "Primary key" that you are trying to get (and modify) defined in a SQL Server table or from something else?

Comment: From SQL Server Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if is there any better solution but this is working :

**For the Primary key :**

```
 Public Function Get_PK(ctx As MyEntities, entity As Object) As String
    Dim objectContext = DirectCast(ctx, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
    Dim t As Type = entity.GetType.BaseType 
    Dim m As MethodInfo = objectContext.GetType().GetMethod("CreateObjectSet", New Type() {})
    Dim generic As MethodInfo = m.MakeGenericMethod(t)
    Dim st As Object = generic.Invoke(objectContext, Nothing)
    Dim entitySetPI As PropertyInfo = st.GetType().GetProperty("EntitySet")
    Dim entitySet As Metadata.Edm.EntitySet = DirectCast(entitySetPI.GetValue(st, Nothing), Metadata.Edm.EntitySet)
    Dim keyNames As IEnumerable(Of String) = entitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.[Select](Function(k) k.Name)
    Return keyNames(0)
End Function
```

How I use :

Read the value :

```
MessageBox.Show(CallByName(MyObject1, Get_PK(context, MyObject1), CallType.Get).ToString)
```

Modify the value :

```
CallByName(MyObject1, Get_PK(context, MyObject1), CallType.Let, 7)
```

.........................

**For the Parent Property :**

```
  Public Function Get_FK(ctx As MyEntities, entity As Object, parenttable As String) As String
    Dim objectCont = DirectCast(ctx, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
    Dim t As Type = entity.GetType.BaseType
    Dim m As MethodInfo = objcont.GetType().GetMethod("CreateObjectSet", New Type() {})
    Dim generic As MethodInfo = m.MakeGenericMethod(t)
    Dim st As Object = generic.Invoke(objcont, Nothing)
    Dim entitySetPI As PropertyInfo = st.GetType().GetProperty("EntitySet")
    Dim entitySet As Metadata.Edm.EntitySet = DirectCast(entitySetPI.GetValue(st, Nothing), Metadata.Edm.EntitySet)
    Dim elementtype = entitySet.ElementType
    Dim entitymember = elementtype.NavigationProperties.Where(Function(t1) t1.ToEndMember.Name = parenttable)
    Return entitymember.First.GetDependentProperties.First.Name
End Function
```

How I use :

Read the value :

```
MessageBox.Show(CallByName(MyObject1, Get_FK(context, MyObject1,"Parentobj"), CallType.Get).ToString)
```

To modify the value :

```
CallByName(MyObject1, Get_FK(context, MyObject1,"Parentobj"), CallType.Let, 7)
```